# JQuery returns JSON object with 404

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm quite new to the whole jQuery/JSON thing but thought I would give it a go. The idea is that I am posting data to a PHP script and then returning a JSON object. This works fine on my localhost but on the web server, Firebug shows that the JSON object is being returned but I also get a 404 error.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Javascript -

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
  $('#graph').empty();
  var area = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/vote",
    cache: false,
    data: "area=" + area,
    success: function(json) {

      arrayOfData = new Array(
        [json.science_graph, 'Science', '#009999'],
        [json.maths_graph, 'Maths', '#FF6600'],
        [json.ict_graph, 'ICT', '#FF0000'],
        [json.mfl_graph, 'MFL', '#FFCC00'],
        [json.dt_graph, 'Design Technology', '#33CC00'],
        [json.other_graph, 'Other Events', '#003399']
      );
      $('#graph').jqBarGraph({
        data: arrayOfData,
        barSpace: 5,
        width: 430
      });

    }
  });
});
```

PHP -

```
 if ($vote == true)
   {
    $poll = $this->ts_model->graph_poll();

    list($maths, $science, $ict, $dt, $mfl, $other) = $poll;

    echo "{";
    echo "\"science_graph\":\"".$science."\",";
    echo "\"ict_graph\":\"".$ict."\",";
    echo "\"dt_graph\":\"".$dt."\",";
    echo "\"other_graph\":\"".$other."\",";
    echo "\"mfl_graph\":\"".$mfl."\",";
    echo "\"maths_graph\":\"".$maths."\"";
    echo "}";
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is ".vote"?  I suggest changing that "click" handler so that it has

```
return false;
```

as the last line. My (barely warranted) guess is that ".vote" is either a submit button or an `<a>` tag, and that the "click" is triggering both your handler and the native action. If the handler returns `false` then the native action won't proceed.

Comment: ".vote" is an <a> tag. I have attempted to add return false; but this is not having any effect.

Comment: Are you sure you added `return false;` to the "click" handler function itself, and not the AJAX response handler?  You can use something like the Firefox TamperData plugin to see *all* the HTTP requests your page makes. That might help you see if the problem is that your page is submitting *two* requests instead of one. Or, as an experiment, you can change the "href" on the `<a>` tag to be some real URL (http://google.com or whatever).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did everything you said and checked ot TamperData - very good plugin. It turns out in the end that by including a wordpress code snippet <?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>  it was stopping the JSON request from displaying properly.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it works. TamperData is indeed a very useful "sanity check" tool to have around.

Answer (score 0):

If the json call is returning 404 which is a I think what you are saying you need to check that this is working ok. You should be able to put the url you are calling in your browser to get a better idea of what is going on. Once you do this you will be able to tweak it and then add it back into your script.

Comment: I have tested the url for the JSON request and it returns the JSON string - {"science_graph":"3","ict_graph":"3","dt_graph":"7","other_graph":"4","mfl_graph":"4","maths_graph":"2"}.
Firebug is also showing that this is returned when the ajax is fired, however firebug also shows a 404 and the data isn't loaded back into the page which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mod rewrite is on on your web server. Had the same problem and turns out the 404 was because of this line in my htaccess:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```